# Windows Service on Windows Server 2003 R2 - Status is running but seems not to be working

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a Custom windows service built on Net 2.0 and deployed on Windows Server 2003 R2.

It has been working fine for last 3 years but recently I have started facing problem with it.

It worked for some time and then stopped working even if the status is running. 
I tried to stop the service twice but every time it was stuck with error 1053 and I was unable to stop it. Both the times I had to reboot the server because this is the only option I'm left with at the last. However this is not a good solution for Production servers.

Can someone please help in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why the service is not responding, but have you tried [terminating the underlying process](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#StuckPending) when it becomes unresponsive? That may be a better option versus rebooting.